# Groovy Console with defaulted imports

Tags: groovy, groovy-console

Is there a way to start the groovy console with a set of imports already set or variables predefined?

`java -cp <some jar with groovy> org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main`

But before the user even does anything several things have been already imported for them, such as static functions or classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to start the groovy console with a set of imports
> already set or variables predefined?

You can specify expressions to be evaluated at startup time using the `-e` command line switch:

```
groovysh -e "x=5;y=4"
```